# char array corruption - pset6 cs50x

Tags: arrays, corruption

I’ m working on pset6 and I face an unexplained problem. In my trial code I validated request line, I extracted query correctly from request-target and I’m trying to concatenate root and absolute path. In order to test my code, I hardcoded root and request line. My problem is that when I hardcode a long root, after the concatenation of root and absolute-path, my extracted query gets corrupted and gets a value which is part of the variable path, either query exists or is NULL. When the hardcoded root is short, there is no problem and query isn’t corrupted.  The variables query and root do not have any connection between them. Can anyone help me?

My code is C:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    char* line = "GET /cat.jpg?q=Alice HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    char* root = "/home/jharvard/Dropbox/pset6/public";
    // VALIDATE REQUEST LINE

    // check method is GET

    char* val_req = strchr(line, ' ');
    char test_method[val_req - line + 1];
    char* t_method = "GET";
    strncpy(test_method, line, val_req - line);
    test_method[val_req - line] = '\0';
    int valm = strcmp(test_method, t_method);
    /** checks
        printf("val_req = %s\n", val_req);
        printf("test_method = %s\n", test_method);
        printf("valm = %d\n", valm);
        printf("test_method = %s\n", test_method);
        printf("length of test_method = %d\n", strlen(test_method));
        printf("length of t_method = %d\n", strlen(t_method));*/

    if (valm != 0)
    {
        printf("error(405) \n");

    }
    else
    {
        printf(" correct method\n");
    }



    //check request-target
    char* temp = strchr(val_req + 1, ' ');
    char test_req_tar[temp - val_req];
    strncpy(test_req_tar, val_req + 1, temp - val_req + 1);
    test_req_tar[temp - val_req - 1] = '\0';

    /** checks
    printf("val_req = %s\n", val_req);
    printf("temp = %s\n", temp);
    printf("test_req_tar = %s\n", test_req_tar);*/

    char* find_dot = strchr(test_req_tar, '.');
    char* find_doubles = strchr(test_req_tar, '"');
    if (test_req_tar[0] != '/')
    {
        printf("error (501)");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" correct initial slash\n");
    }
    if (find_dot == NULL)
    {
        printf("error (501 dot)\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" correct dot\n");
    }
    if (find_doubles != NULL)
    {
        printf("error (400)\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" correct no doubles\n");
    }

    //check version of HTTP
    char* val_ver = strstr(temp, "HTTP/1.1");
    if (val_ver == NULL)
    {
        printf("error (505)\n");  
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" correct HTTP-version\n");
    }


    // EXTRACT QUERY FROM REQUEST-TARGET

    char* temp1 = strchr(test_req_tar, '?');
    int len = 1;
    if (temp1 != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(temp1);

    }
   char query[len];
   if (temp1 == NULL)
   {
      strcpy(query, "\0");

   }
   else
   {
        strcpy(query, temp1 + 1);
   }

    /* ELEGXOI


    printf("len = %d\n", len);
    printf("size of query %d\n", sizeof(query));  
    printf("query = %s\n", query);
    printf("temp1 = %s\n", temp1);
    printf("test_req_tar = %s\n", test_req_tar);*/

    // CONCATENATE ROOT AND ABSOLUTE PATH


    int lt = 0;
    int lt1 = 0;
    char temp2[strlen(test_req_tar)+1];
    strcpy(temp2, test_req_tar);
    printf("\n**** BEFORE CONCATENATIONS ****\n\n");
    printf("query:%s\n", query);
    printf("test_req_tar:%s\n", test_req_tar);
    printf("temp1: %s\n", temp1);
    printf("temp2: %s\n", temp2);

    if (temp1 == NULL)
    {
        lt1 = strlen(temp2);
    }
    else
    {
        lt1 = temp1 - test_req_tar;
    }
    char path[lt], absol_path[lt1+1];
    strncpy(absol_path, temp2, lt1);
    absol_path[lt1] = '\0';

    lt = strlen(root) + strlen(absol_path);
    strcpy(path, root);
    strcat(path, absol_path);
    printf("\n**** AFTER CONCATENATIONS ****\n\n");
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    printf("query: %s\n", query);
    printf("test_req_tar: %s\n", test_req_tar);
    printf("temp1: %s\n", temp1);
    printf("temp2: %s\n\n", temp2);


}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your code (or actually, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), any tracebacks and a tag for whatever language you're using (I'm guessing C or C++?)

Comment: I edited my question adding my code. My code is written in c

Comment: The code for     char* root = "/home";
works properly. The query is not corrupted